# How to reference docker image location across cloud providers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to reference docker registry information as part of the image declaration in docker-compose.yaml in a flexible fashion, if the docker images get published into cloud provider specific registry. For example, the docker image could be present in any of the repositories or could be present in the local system

```
https://hub.docker.com/myrepo
https://gcr.io/myrepo
https://myaccount.azure.io/myrepo
```

We currently use a .env variable (say REGISTRY_VENDOR to indicate where it is)
image: $REGISTRY_VENDOR/app-web:$APP_WEB_IMAGE_TAG

How to reference this if the image is present in local machine or if its in a cloud provider specific repo

Comment: I think environment variables as you have them are in fact the best practice (maybe with shorter names).  What's not working with that approach?

Comment: I can specify REGISTRY_VENDOR for all cloud providers, but how can I refer if the file is available only in locally built, then the $REGISTRY_VENDOR/ prefix is not useful.

Comment: You can use any value for the local tag; so long as you don't `docker-compose push` the built images it doesn't really matter.